# "brew" command not found after installing Homebrew on an Arm/M1 Mac

Tags: mac, zsh, homebrew

I have installed Homebrew using:

```
$ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Why is the `brew` command not found?

```
(base) rags@Rageshs-Mac-mini ~ % brew help
zsh: command not found: brew
```

My `$PATH` variable according to the shell:

```
(base) rags@Rageshs-Mac-mini ~ % echo $path
/Users/rags/opt/anaconda3/bin /Users/rags/opt/anaconda3/condabin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

Comment: Why do you have a lower-case "path" variable? Shouldn't it be all caps? I'm suspicious of how your shell environment is set up.

Comment: Maybe it's case insensitive?

Comment: There should be some questions asked by the install script, and some output.  Can you share that?  Also, is there anything installed in `/opt/homebrew`?  If not, then the install didn't work.  If there is (and I mean like a LOT of stuff), then the install might have worked but it might have failed to configure your shell properly.  You mostly just need add `/opt/homebrew/bin` to your $PATH in your shell config file (which could be `.profile`, `.bashrc`, or `.zshrc`), like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530090/adding-a-new-entry-to-the-path-variable-in-zsh

Answer (score 7):

Homebrew isn't included in your `$PATH` variable, which is the cause of the shell not finding the `brew` command.

To fix this, you must edit your shell startup script, `.zshrc`. The Homebrew installer doesn't make this edit, but rather instructs the user to do it, which you probably missed.

Add the following line to `.zshrc`:

```
eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

You can either add it with a text editor or by executing a shell command:

```
$ echo 'eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >> $HOME/.zshrc
```

Now, reload the shell by opening a new shell window and you should be good to go.

---

## Explanation

The lines in `.zshrc` are executed each time you open a new shell.

When the shell reaches the line

```
eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

it will at first execute

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv
```

, that is, executing the `brew` binary, given with its full path, with `shellenv` provided as an argument. From `man brew`:

```
    shellenv
        Print export statements. When run in  a  shell,  this  installation  of
        Homebrew will be added to your PATH, MANPATH, and INFOPATH.

        The  variables HOMEBREW_PREFIX, HOMEBREW_CELLAR and HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY
        are also exported to  avoid  querying  them  multiple  times.  Consider
        adding  evaluation  of  this  command's  output  to your dotfiles (e.g.
        ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile, or ~/.zprofile) with:  eval  $(brew  shel-
        lenv)
```

Indeed, the output of `brew shellenv` is:

```
$ brew shellenv
export HOMEBREW_PREFIX="/opt/homebrew";
export HOMEBREW_CELLAR="/opt/homebrew/Cellar";
export HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY="/opt/homebrew";
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin${PATH+:$PATH}";
export MANPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/man${MANPATH+:$MANPATH}:";
export INFOPATH="/opt/homebrew/share/info:${INFOPATH:-}";
```

So in effect, the shell startup script executes `eval $(...)`, with `...` replaced by the lines above.